# To divide a a loop variable per se and save in another one to be used later

Tags: variable-substitution, math

I am facing a problem with bash script: I have a set of variables 'i' that ranges from 3.31 up to 3.35. My script prints out, as a function of the variable 'i' some input file for geometrical optimization. The point is that I need to change the $i variable in the path of the script to an integer for efficiency reasons.

I thought to divide the variable every time by itself, store it in another variable called e.g. ans, and use $ans into my script so that the output is properly fine. Can you kindly suggest to me how to fix this problem? It looks like it is not possible to divide a variable per se.
Thanks in advance

Here and example of how i would do this stuff:

```
for i in `seq 3.31 0.01 3.35`  
do
  ...
     touch file$i.dat      
echo "%nproc=6" >> file$i.dat

ans=$(($i/$i))

echo "%chk=$PWD/conf$ans/s0.chk" >> file$i.dat
```

Comment: In bash, you can divide *integers* (whether they are variables or fixed) e.g. `echo $((6/2))` or `i=6; j=2; echo $((i/j))` but arithmetic on floating point values is not supported. In any case, how would dividing `$i` by itself help? The answer will always be 1.

Comment: yep, you're right... sorry, i wrote without thinking too much... let's say in other words: I have a a fix value (3.31), and i want to divide the numbers in the 'i' series by 3.31. I know that bash does not support the floating points... are there any alternatives, like awk or else for example?

Comment: Consider generating an integer sequence instead e.g. `for i in {331..335}` and then converting it to a decimal as required using `bc` for example `printf 'scale = 2; %d/100\n' $i | bc`